# How to add a second consumer to a pthread-based producer-consumer setup?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I currently have two threads for a producer-consumer setup, which uses `pthread_cond_wait()` and `pthread_cond_signal()` to alternate between reading in data and processing it.

Say I have a lock, two conditions, and a Boolean flag that states if the data buffer has data in it:

```
pthread_mutex_t lock;
pthread_cond_t we_have_data;
pthread_cond_t we_need_data;
bool buffer_is_empty = true;
```

I have a `pthread_t` that uses the following function to produce data (read data into a buffer):

```
static void* produce(void* arg) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    for (;;) {
        while (!buffer_is_empty) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&we_need_data, &lock);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        // read some data into our buffer
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        buffer_is_empty = false;
        pthread_cond_signal(&we_have_data);
    }
}
```

Then I have a second `pthread_t` that uses the following code to consume that data, upon receiving the `we_have_data` signal:

```
static void* consume(void* arg) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    for (;;) {
        while (buffer_is_empty) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&we_have_data, &lock);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        // process the data in our buffer
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        buffer_is_empty = true;
        pthread_cond_signal(&we_need_data);
    }
}
```

This works correctly.

What I would now like to do is add a third thread that does work on the data from the `consume()` function, if the buffer contains certain data.

I had tried adding a third condition, but my program hangs.

I set up a condition and Boolean flag:

```
bool processing_with_second_consumer;
pthread_cond_t we_need_to_process_data_with_another_consumer;
```

Then I modify the consumer:

```
static void* consume(void* arg) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    for (;;) {
        while (buffer_is_empty && !processing_with_second_consumer) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&we_have_data, &lock);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        // process the data in our buffer
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        if (data_meets_our_conditions) {
            processing_with_second_consumer = true;
            pthread_cond_signal(&we_need_to_process_data_with_another_consumer);
        }
        buffer_is_empty = true;
        pthread_cond_signal(&we_need_data);
    }
}
```

And then I modify the producer to wait on the boolean:

```
static void* produce(void* arg) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    for (;;) {
        while (!buffer_is_empty && !processing_with_second_consumer) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&we_need_data, &lock);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        // read some data into our buffer
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        buffer_is_empty = false;
        pthread_cond_signal(&we_have_data);
    }
}
```

And add a third thread to consume from the consumer:

```
static void* consume_from_the_consumer(void* arg) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    for (;;) {
        while (!buffer_is_empty && processing_with_second_consumer) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&we_need_to_process_data_with_another_consumer, &lock);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        // do more specific processing of the data in our buffer
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        processing_with_second_consumer = false;
    }
}
```

I can't seem to get the program to exit correctly — it basically hangs in an infinite loop on consuming from the consumer.

How does one correctly set up signaling with pthread conditions, in order to allow a third (or fourth, or fifth, etc.) thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this for three threads, I needed to make a few changes:

1. Move the mutex lock into the thread loop; the first thing a loop should do is lock the data, and the last thing it should do is unlock it.
2. Set up three `bool` flags: `is_new_line_available`, `is_new_subdata_available`, and `is_eof`.
3. Set up three `pthread_cond_t` conditions: `new_line_is_available`, `new_line_is_empty`, and `new_subdata_is_available`.
4. Make sure every thread has a condition in which `pthread_exit()` is called to terminate that thread.

The produce thread:

```
static void* produce(void* arg) {
    for (;;) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        while (is_new_line_available) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&new_line_is_empty, &lock);
        }
        // ... read a line of data into buffer ...
        if (EOF) {
            is_new_line_available = true;
            is_new_subdata_available = true;
            is_eof = false;
            pthread_cond_signal(&new_line_is_available);
            pthread_cond_signal(&new_subdata_is_available);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }
        is_new_line_available = true;
        is_new_chromosome_available = false;
        is_eof = false;
        pthread_cond_signal(&new_line_is_available);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    }
}
```

The consume thread:

```
static void* consume(void* arg) {
    for (;;) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        while (is_new_line_available) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&new_line_is_available, &lock);
        }
        // ... process line of data to look for subdata type ... 
        if (EOF) {
            is_eof = true;
            pthread_cond_signal(&new_subdata_is_available);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }
        else if (subdata_found) {
            is_new_subdata_available = true;
            is_new_line_available = false;
            pthread_cond_signal(&new_line_is_empty);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    }
}
```

Then the third "subdata"-handling thread:

```
static void* consume_subdata_from_the_consumer(void* arg) {
    for (;;) {
        if (is_eof) {
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        while (!is_new_subdata_available) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&new_subdata_is_available, &lock);
        }
        // ... process subdata ...
        is_new_subdata_available = false;
        is_new_line_available = true;
        pthread_cond_signal(new_line_is_available);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    }
}
```

Some observations:

- All threads should have a condition that gets them to a `pthread_exit()`, or the parent process will hang.
- It is necessary to pull all code that modifies state in between lock and unlock directives, or data that gets processed out-of-order can leave to corruption.
- Any buffer overflows or writing to initialized data can cause problems. Use `calloc()`, for instance, to initialize a character buffer before using it in a thread.

Answer (score 1):

You producer only signals `we_have_data`. But since it sets `buffer_is_empty` to false, it can make the `consume_from_the_consumer` thread ready to go, but it doesn't unblock it because it's blocked on a second condition variable.

To make your life simpler, I'd suggest two changes:

1. Always use `pthread_cond_broadcast`.
2. Only use one condition variable.

This may be very slightly less efficient, but there are several entire categories of subtle bugs that it makes impossible.

Comment: I'm not able to get this working, it seems. With three threads and one "on/off" condition, two threads would be unblocked at a given time. Do you have an example of how this would work?

Comment: @AlexReynolds Two threads would be unblocked, but the "wrong" one would immediately block again. That's what the `while` loop is for. What went wrong when you tried it?

Comment: My program hangs on processing data.

Comment: @AlexReynolds Can you post your code somewhere? There should always be one thread that can make forward progress.

Comment: Compare line 184 to line 190 -- that can't be right.

Comment: If I change line 184 to `while (!sb->line_has_data) {`, then the program never calls or unblocks that thread (`chromosome_name_changed_thread`). If I instead change line 190 to `sb->line_has_data = false;` the program stays inside that thread in an infinite loop and never leaves.

Comment: @AlexReynolds You're going to have to fix everything. Work through the series of state changes and make sure all the code is right. Clearly it's not right now, so change it to what it needs to be and then re-test. (You should only be broadcasting a condvar if you changed some state that another thread might be waiting for under the protection of the mutex.)

Comment: The code works correctly for the two threads `produce_bed_thread` and `consume_bed_thread`. It's only when I instantiate the third thread and join it that the program hangs or enters an infinite loop.